# How do I exclude all the values outside a circle of an image using TensorFlow operations?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

This is what I mean:
using the following code, I am able to let values outside a circle become 0. The code generates an all-white image and set values outside a circle be zero.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

width = 512
all_white_img = np.zeros(shape=[width, width], dtype=np.float)
all_white_img[:] = 1
plt.imshow(all_white_img, cmap='gray', vmax=1.0, vmin=0.0)
plt.show()

[X, Y] = np.mgrid[0:width, 0:width]
xpr = X - int(width) // 2
ypr = Y - int(width) // 2
radius = width // 2
reconstruction_circle = (xpr ** 2 + ypr ** 2) <= radius ** 2 #set circle
all_white_img[~reconstruction_circle] = 0.
plt.imshow(all_white_img, cmap='gray', vmax=1.0, vmin=0.0)
plt.show()
```

Output images:
[image]
[image]

How do I do the same thing using TensorFlow efficiently?

Because numpy runs on CPU and I need something able to run on GPU.

The code is just an example, I need something that works not only for circles but also any other shapes.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `tf.where` function does exactly what I want.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf

width = 512
sess = tf.Session()

[X, Y] = np.mgrid[0:width, 0:width]
xpr = X - int(width) // 2
ypr = Y - int(width) // 2
radius = width // 2
reconstruction_circle = (xpr ** 2 + ypr ** 2) <= radius ** 2  #set circle

all_white_img = tf.ones(shape=[width, width], dtype=tf.float32)
plt.imshow(sess.run(all_white_img), cmap='gray', vmax=1.0, vmin=0.0)
plt.show()
reconstruction_circle = tf.cast(reconstruction_circle, tf.bool)
all_white_img = tf.where(reconstruction_circle, all_white_img, tf.zeros_like(all_white_img))
plt.imshow(sess.run(all_white_img), cmap='gray', vmax=1.0, vmin=0.0)
plt.show()
```